# Sublime Text - duplicate line "ctrl+shift+d" not working

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a problem in my favorite editor Sublime text, I can't do a duplicate line with the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> default, but if I change it, it works.

I don't want to change it, and i want that works for me.

Please any help, Thanks.

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: It seems like this person had a similar issue. Maybe try updating your python version and changing your `PYTHONHOME` environment var
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6988

Comment: Version Python 2.7, but what are the common things between sublime text and python ?

Comment: the python version on your machine has nothing to do with Sublime Text, which ships with its own internal version.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+D` works for me in sublime3, unbuntu .

Answer (score 15):

Check out @skuroda's [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts) plugin, available through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net). You probably have another plugin installed that also uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> as a shortcut, and FindKeyConflicts will help you find out which, so you can change it and keep Sublime's default.

Comment: I'vd tested it but i didn't any conflict of this key, also I'vd re-install sublime text :S no results ..

Comment: @kach Try entering `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the console. Then hit your keyboard short cut. Can you tell us what command comes up?

Comment: ive tried this too. other keys and clicks is as expected. eg: ctrl+c it shows "command: copy".
ctrl+shift+d shows nothing.
"FindKeyConflicts: All Key Maps to Buffer" showing ctrl+shift+d binds to duplicate_line only

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to bring this up, I know it's old, but I'm on the exact same situation. Apart from trying everything which was suggested before without any success, I made a really odd discovery by logging keyboard events to the console:

- If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, it does not work. ST does not recognize the keypress.
- If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, it works and ST recognizes the keypress.
- If, **after pressing** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, **I lift my finger from Alt, pressing D repeatedly makes ST recognize** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. I can also release Shift and press it again and still works. It works **until I release** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **key**. Then pressing again <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>does nothing, again.

Testing the same sequence out of the console, in the edition window, line duplication works again with this trick. Anyway, it's a pain in the *ss and I'm afraid there's some kind of bug in the key handling code. Hope this helps fixing it.

Comment: FYI, after updating ST3 to 3114 version, shift+ctrl+d key works again as usual for me. Maybe a bug fix?

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if PluginHost.exe crashes. Completely killing all ST processes and relaunching can fix that.

Answer (score 5):

You can add that code in your preferences

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "duplicate_line" }
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem like that.
In my case it was a screen recorder software called Icecream Screen Recorder.
When I closed the program it worked fine.

Try to close some processes and find wich causing this.

Comment: Works. Thank you

Comment: Apparently Snagit has this as a keybind for entering draw mode while recording a video. File > Capture preferences... > Hotkeys tab, set the corresponding dropdown to 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

Num Lock was on in my case. Turning it off worked for me!